# Make jquery.load happen before HTML load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap navbar in a file, `navbar.html` and I load it into my HTML page with `Jquery.load()`

I have this at the bottom of my HTML page:

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(function(){
   $("#navbar-partial").load("navbar.html"); 
});
</script>
```

and `<div id="navbar-partial></div>` is in the HTML page.

After the navbar-partial I have a main-content div with everything else on the page.  The main-content loads first, and then the navbar does which looks "tacky".  If i put the navbar code in every file it loads first and appears to never change, loads fast, but I want to extract the code into one file so I dont have to edit it everywhere.

Any ideas on have to make the navbar-partial load first or faster?  I moved the script tags into the head and that didnt help either.

Thanks

Comment: What server technology are you using (PHP? ASP/MVC?) as AJAX *is not* the best solution to this problem.

Comment: I just have HTML pages with JS files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$(function(){` delays the load until the DOM is "ready".

So long as your code comes *after* the div it references this will speed things up a little:

```
<div id="navbar-partial></div>
<script> 
    $("#navbar-partial").load("navbar.html"); 
</script>
```

You are still dependent on the loading delay, so do not expect miracles :)

The proper solution to this problem is normally a server-side thing, but as you are using plain HTML files, this will have to do for now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the best way of having a partial menu.

But to make it load earlier, just remove the 'dom ready' part.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>$("#navbar-partial").load("navbar.html");</script>
```

And put that inside the #navbar-partial element in your HTML, and it will work.

I would however suggest that you look in to using a server side include, which AFAIK most web servers support. then all you'd need is something like this

```
<!--#include virtual="navbar.html" -->
```

You can read more about them here: http://www.ssi.su/#include